# Unable to install heroku core plugins

Tags: windows, heroku

Windows 8.1, 64b

Last week all worked.

Whenever I run a heroku command it tries to install the heroku core plugins, example:

```
C:\Users\Usr\Documents\Aptana3_Workspace\mobile-site>heroku run
Installing core plugins heroku-apps, heroku-fork, heroku-git, heroku-local, heroku-run, heroku-status...
 ?    module.js:338
 ?        throw err;
 ?        ^
 ?
 ?    Error: Cannot find module './bin/npm-cli.js'
 ?        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
 ?        at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
 ?        at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
 ?        at require (module.js:384:17)
 ?        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Local\heroku\node-v4.1.1-windows-x86\lib\node_modules\npm\cli.js:2:1)
 ?        at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
 ?        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
 ?        at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
 ?        at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
 ?        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
 !    `run` is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant `-h`, `2fa`, `auth`, `join`, `open`, `orgs`, `pg`, `ps` or `rake`.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.

C:\Users\Usr\Documents\Aptana3_Workspace\mobile-site>
```

While the some commands work, even when showing the error msg:

```
C:\Users\Usr\Documents\Aptana3_Workspace\mobile-site>heroku restart
Installing core plugins heroku-apps, heroku-fork, heroku-git, heroku-local, heroku-run, heroku-status...
 ?    module.js:338
 ?        throw err;
 ?        ^
 ?
 ?    Error: Cannot find module './bin/npm-cli.js'
 ?        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
 ?        at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
 ?        at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
 ?        at require (module.js:384:17)
 ?        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Local\heroku\node-v4.1.1-windows-x86\lib\node_modules\npm\cli.js:2:1)
 ?        at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
 ?        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
 ?        at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
 ?        at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
 ?        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
Restarting dynos... failed
 !    You do not have access to the app mobile-site.

C:\Users\Usr\Documents\Aptana3_Workspace\mobile-site>
```

I reinstalled heroku, searched the web but no success..

Any ideas?
Thx.

Comment: Just started happening to me as well - and I am on Linux.  It worked yesterday - not sure what they broke or why.  The term "backwards compatibility" seems lost, today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was:

Delete %LOCALAPPDATA%\heroku folder and try again (run heroku command)

I didn't think of this, I didn't even know this folder existed- That's what Heroku support said- so credit for him :)

p.s. to know where %LOCALAPPDATA% is just write in the console (windows)

```
echo %LOCALAPPDATA%
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well on Windows.  I turned off and back on command prompt window, reinstalled Heroku toolbelt and redeployed my app to Heroku, problem got solved.